# How to search by DateTimeOffset in C# Nest Elasticsearch?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to know how to use DateTimeOffset in the DateRangeQuery class in C# Nest Elasticsearch.
In my index, I am storing the date data including TimeZone as shown below.
"2023-05-19T02:07:36.602171+00:00"

The DateMath class I use in this class seems to be compatible with just DateTime.
I would like to be able to retrieve it along with the TimeZone.

This is my C# code.

```
 new SearchRequest<MyLog>("my_index")
        {
            Query = new QueryContainer(
                new BoolQuery
                {
                    Must = new QueryContainer[]
                    {
                        
                        new DateRangeQuery
                        {
                            GreaterThanOrEqualTo = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
                            LessThanOrEqualTo =    DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.addHour(4)
                        }
                    }
                })
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NEST client for Elasticsearch in C# does not directly support DateTimeOffset in the DateRangeQuery. You can convert your DateTimeOffset to `ISO 8601 format`.

```
new SearchRequest<MyLog>("my_index")
{
    Query = new QueryContainer(
        new BoolQuery
        {
            Must = new QueryContainer[]
            {
                new DateRangeQuery
                {
                    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("o"),
                    LessThanOrEqualTo = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(4).ToString("o")
                }
            }
        })
};
```

> In this code, the "o" format specifier represents a round-trip
> date/time pattern; when this standard format specifier is used with a
> DateTimeOffset value, it includes the minute and second of the offset
> in the result string.

[image]

##### push the test data

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "date" : "2023-08-07T12:07:36.602171+00:00" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "date" : "2023-08-07T11:07:36.602171+00:00" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "date" : "2023-05-19T04:07:36.602171+00:00" }
```

##### test with an example query

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "gte": "now",
        "lte": "now+4h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```